# Is there an HTML Helper library (similar to Rose) that doesn't clash with Dancer2?

Tags: perl, dancer

So I've been developing with Dancer2 for about a week using Dancer2, DBIx::Class and Rose::HTML

The trouble I'm having is that I can't get Rose to fill out a form based on Dancer2's 'params'

Does anyone know how to make this work? Or know another library I might find useful?